# React-Native - Switch onValueChange input refers to wrong field

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I need to create a class wich automatically creates several `Objects` (Text & Switch pairs) on the basis of a `JSON` and the `Switch` should fetch different `values` when the `onValueChange` event is triggered.

**The issue:** If you look at the following code. The function `switchChanged` just fetches the last incoming `field` (location). Strange here is: The above `Text` fields all get the right value handed over. `Just at the onValueChange function i get only the last field handed over`

*I deleted all styles to get easier read through*

- Json looks like the following:

```js
module.exports = {
    "reminders":
    {
        "title": "Erinnerungen",
        "description": "Sollten Sie Favoriten gesetzt haben, können Sie uns hier erlauben Sie an die Events zu erinnern.",
        "startvalue": true
    },
    "noIntro":
    {
        "title": "Introseite",
        "description": "Wenn Sie wollen können Sie die beim ersten Start gezeigte Introseite bei jedem Start anzeigen lassen.",
        "startvalue": true
    },
    "location":
    {
        "title": "GPS erlauben",
        "description": "Erlauben Sie ihrem Smartphone das GPS für unsere Campuskarte zu benutzen.",
        "startvalue": true
    }
}
```

- Class (Settings) where the magic should happen:

```js
//There i require the above JSON
var settingIndex = require('../../settingIndex');

class Settings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }
  
  getSettingBox(){
        var Settings = [];
        var object = {};

        for (var topicKey in settingIndex){
            var value = SettingStorage.get().filtered('key = "' + topicKey + '"')[0].value;
            var title = settingIndex[topicKey].title;
            var description = settingIndex[topicKey].description;

            object=(
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{title}</Text>
                        <Text>{description}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Switch
                        onTintColor={styleHelper.colors.ACCENT_COLOR}
                        onValueChange={(value) => this.switchChanged(topicKey, value)}
                        value={value}/>
                </View>
            );
            Settings.push(object)
        }
        return Settings;
    }

    render() {
        var Settings = this.getSettingBox();
        return(
            <View>
                <View>
                    {Settings}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    switchChanged(field, value) {
        console.log("Feld: " + field + "--- Value: " + value);
        var obj = {};
        obj[field] = value;
        SettingStorage.set({
            key: field,
            value: value
        });
        this.setState(obj);           
    }
}
```

- Further informations:

**The SettingStorage is my own class where i can save and get stuff from/to Realm**

**The startvalue is set initial at the first start of the app**

Thank you very much in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay 5 minutes after asking I know the answer. After felt 3000 hours of despair.

**The issue:** At the `getSettingBox()` I changed the `for(var topicKey in settingIndex)` to `for(let topicKey in settingIndex)`. So the issue seems to be the lifecycle of the variable/let.

I wont close this question maybe someone has the same issue and freaks out like me.

Greetings